# What does SAFE stand for in the RAI ecosystem?

Tags: dai, stablecoins, makerdao

The [SAFEEngine](https://docs.reflexer.finance/system-contracts/core/safe-engine#2-contract-details) is analogous to [Vat.sol](https://github.com/makerdao/dss/blob/master/src/vat.sol) in DAI.

What does SAFE stand for?

Comment: I think it stems from the 'Gnosis Safe' terminology tbh, but might be a better question for just tagging ameen on twitter

Comment: ameen who? Are they a reflexer labs person?

Comment: @ameensol, I thought better of you Patrick lol.  He's one of the early founders/backers and probably main twitter shill for rai

Comment: Welp, twitter is down, guess I'll never know.